# openweathermap forecast api all result same city

Tags: api, forecasting, openweathermap

I use openweathermap api forecast by lat & lon.
I don't understand all lat & lon result has same city ,and city didn't change in
result by lat & lon.

Thanks for any guides.
Regards
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you're using the wrong base URL.  You should ensure that you're using `http://api.openweathermap.org` and not `http://samples.openweathermap.org`.